# SVN: Track merges

Tags: svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, merge-tracking

Is it possible in SVN 1.6 to track where a commit was merged. I'm especially interesting in UI based solution ([Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) plugin will be great).

Comment: You have to be a little more specific, because the notion of "merging a commit" doesn't work 100% in subversion.

Comment: I've a commit which have to be merged in couple branches. Later I wish to known in which branches (where and whom) the commit was merged. It works in opposite way (merged commit shows it's origin).

Comment: The difficulty of merging and managing merges with SVN is the reason we switched to P4.  I think your best bet may be to just grep for the changed line across the repo and see which branches it shows up in.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html

Comment: The best way to track merges in SVN I found was to use very descriptive commit messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all answered person (special thanks to [derobert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27727/derobert) and [Jim T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7298/jim-t)). I write my own code using svnkit 1.2.x that do what I exactly need.

```
private static void showMergedRevision(String pFromUrl, String pToUrl) throws SVNException {
    List<String> folders= new ArrayList<String>();
    folders.add("Folder1");
    ...

    SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();

     String name="user";
     String password="password";

     ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions( true );

     ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);

     SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance( options , authManager );

     final Set<Long> mergedRevision = new HashSet<Long>();        
     for(String folder : folders){
         SVNURL svnFrom = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(pFromUrl + "/" + folder);
         SVNURL svnTo = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(pToUrl+ "/" + folder);
         ISVNLogEntryHandler mergedLogger = new ISVNLogEntryHandler() {
            public void handleLogEntry(SVNLogEntry pParamSVNLogEntry) throws SVNException {
                mergedRevision.add(pParamSVNLogEntry.getRevision());
            }
        };
        ourClientManager.getDiffClient().doGetLogMergedMergeInfo(svnTo, SVNRevision.HEAD, svnFrom, SVNRevision.HEAD, false, null, mergedLogger);
     }

     System.out.println(String.format("Tracking merges from [%s] to [%s].", pFromUrl, pToUrl));
     System.out.println("Comparing folders: " + folders);

     SVNURL svnUrlorg = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(pFromUrl);
     ISVNLogEntryHandler histroyLogger= new ISVNLogEntryHandler() {
        public void handleLogEntry(SVNLogEntry pParamSVNLogEntry) throws SVNException {
            if (pParamSVNLogEntry.getRevision() < 0){
                // Sometimes got -1 null null null values. Skip them
                return;
            }
            final boolean merged = mergedRevision.contains(pParamSVNLogEntry.getRevision());
            System.out.println(String.format("%s %s: %s %s %s", merged ? "[+]": "[-]", 
                    pParamSVNLogEntry.getRevision(), 
                    pParamSVNLogEntry.getAuthor(), pParamSVNLogEntry.getDate(), 
                    pParamSVNLogEntry.getMessage()));
        }
    }; 
    ourClientManager.getLogClient().doLog(svnUrlorg, null, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.create(0), SVNRevision.HEAD, true, false, false, -1, null, histroyLogger);
}
```

The output will be:

> [-] 7210: boa 03.07.2009
>   [-] 7211: boa 03.07.2009
>   [+] 7215: boa 03.07.2009

[+] means merged revision, [-] - unmerged.

Answer (score 9):

I once wrote a quite web-page that kind of did this. I can't give you the page, unfortunately, but I can give you an idea of what I did.

First our development model - all development made to trunk, revisions then get merged into various release branches for different versions of products.

I set up a web page with a column for each version and a row for each trunk revision.
By running svn mergeinfo   for each column, I got back the list of trunk revisions that had been merged in to that version.

So we ended up with something very similar to those feature comparison lists you get - a table showing a black dot for each version that contained the corresponding trunk commit.

Looked a bit like this:

```
rev   |  ver1  |  ver1.1  |  ver2  | ver2.1  |
200   |        |          |        |    X    |
198   |        |    X     |        |    X    |
177   |        |          |        |    X    |
176   |        |          |   X    |    X    |
157   |   X    |    X     |   X    |    X    |
146   |   X    |    X     |   X    |    X    |
122   |   X    |    X     |   X    |    X    |
075   |   X    |    X     |   X    |    X    |
```

This let us see exactly what each version contained (useful for testing), as well as highlighting if any revisions were merged into one place but not another.

Comment: +1 Very nice idea. Feature request for svn mergeinfotable -r 200:75 --source repo/branches , anyone?

Comment: +1 I just built something like this for our team and it's proven very useful. Thanks for sharing the idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an Eclipse plugin, you could try [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). It is really easy to use and has been very useful to me in merging conflicted files and branching, merging branches etc...
Here are some [screenshots](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=2A422C05537796D4E4AEDCB620160B78?pageID=rr1TIx).