# Searching svn commits

Tags: svn, version-control

Another "this ought to be easy but I don't know how to do it" question ...

We have an SVN repository with many many branches. Is there any way to ask a question like "What are all the commits I did in the last week against all branches?" or "What are all the revisions that include changes to file X across all branches?"

I can do a log on a particular branch and search it to get answers to questions like this for one branch, but how do I ask questions like this where the answer may span multiple branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Branches aren't special to Subversion, they're just directories. So asking "what did I commit last week" is no different on a single directory, an entire branch, or an entire repository. Remember you can do this on the entire repository without checking it out by passing the repository URL to `svn log`.

Asking which revisions changed a single file across branches is harder, because as far as Subversion is concerned, those are multiple different files. You'll have to `svn log` the file in each branch, or `svn log` the entire repository and filter.

Answer (score 4):

Example of what @derobert says, assuming today is sept 9 and your trunk/branches/tags are in http://host/svn/project1:

```
svn log -r {2009-09-02T07:00}:HEAD http://host/svn/project1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 3-rd party tools (like [fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)) or an API (like [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)). See relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082699/svn-track-merges).

Answer (score 1):

The show log dialog box in TortoiseSVN has a statistics button that groups commits by author.  That would answer your first question if you happen to be using TortoiseSVN that is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to browse a Subversion repository is to use [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to import your whole repository, branches and all, into a Git repository. Then you can use tools such as [`gitk`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html) to view the repository. Since a Git repository is completely local, tools such as `gitk` have easy access to the entire repository, and they're *fast*, really fast.

Answer (score -1):

Oooh, let's be programmers here...  download the library [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) and roll your own.